# Autonumber in inputting new records

Tags: php, autonumber

My patient number(pnum) need to have a autonumber, like BLHC-2014-0001. I need to automatically have the BLHC-current year-and auto increment of the number with 4 digits when i input new record.

Comment: Well, Where do you store those codes/numbers?

Comment: on my localhost database my variable is pnum

Comment: I don't care about the name of your variable. Post some code showing how, where and when do you need to determine a new number.

Comment: <tr><td>*Patient Number:<input type="text" name="pnum" id="ma"/></td>

Comment: I really doubt someone will be willing or capable to help you unless you really expand your question with proper information about what and how you are trying to achieve something.
Now the only thing I can give you is: ```BLHC-$year-($oldNumber+1)```, but I doubt that'll help you in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function autonum(){                           
    var c ='BLHC-2014-0001';

    var d = c.split("-");
    var e = d[2];
    var f = parseInt(e,10);
    var g = f+1;        
    var str = '' + g;
    var pad = "0000";    
    var resu = str.length < 4 ? (pad+str).slice(-4) : str;
    var lt = d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+resu;               
    document.getElementById("pnum").value =lt;
}
```

Comment: but tell me what happen when number is exceeding 9999?

Comment: show me your whole code and write above code in <?php ?> tag

Comment: <script>
function autonum()
{
$a ='BLHC-2014-0001';
$result = explode('-', $a);

$foo = sprintf('%04d', $result[2] + 1);

var res = $result[0].'-'.$result[1].'-'.$foo;
//{
//var at = new Date();
//var aa = at.getFullYear();
//var a = '0001';
//var bb = 'BLCH-' + aa +'-'+ (a+1);
document.getElementById("pnum").value = res;
}
</script>

Comment: <tr><td>*Patient Number:<input type="text" name="pnum" id="pnum" onfocus="autonum()"/></td>

Comment: <?php
include('connect.php');


   $pnum=$_POST['pnum'];
   $pname=$_POST['pname'];
   $addr=$_POST['addr'];
   $update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblnpatient(pnum, pname, addr)
VALUES
('$pnum','$pname','$addr')");
?>

Comment: //var at = new Date();
//var aa = at.getFullYear();
//var a = '0001';
//var bb = 'BLCH-' + aa +'-'+ (a+1);

Comment: i use this..but the is BLCH-2014-00011

Comment: <script>
function autonum()
{
{ <?php 
$a ='BLHC-2014-0001';
$result = explode('-', $a);

$foo = sprintf('%04d', $result[2] + 1);

$res = $result[0].'-'.$result[1].'-'.$foo;

?>
document.getElementById("pnum").value = res;
}
</script>

Comment: when i focus to the txtbox, nothing appear

Comment: ok..thank you..goodnight

Comment: it works, but the autonumber did not work. it always 0002 . even i save a record

Comment: You have to retrieve last number from database into c variable.
And then you have to perform this operation.

Comment: can you tell me how? please..tnx for the help

Comment: you add BLHC-2014-0001 in your database?
what is your field name which save BLHC-2014-0001?

Comment: the field name also is pnum

Comment: my database is dbnpatient and my table is tblnpatient

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient ORDER BY pnum  DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pn = $row['pnum '];
    break;   
}

And in first statement of function is
var c = '<?php echo $pn; ?>';

Comment: <script>
function autonum(){ 

<?php
include('connect.php')
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient ORDER BY pnum DESC"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $pn = $row['pnum ']; }
?>                          
    var c ='BLHC-2014-0001';

    var d = c.split("-");
    var e = d[2];
    var f = parseInt(e,10);
    var g = f+1;        
    var str = '' + g;
    var pad = "0000";    
    var resu = (pad+str).slice(-pad.length);
    var lt = d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+resu;               
    document.getElementById("pnum").value =lt;
}
</script>

Comment: you have to write code above javascript in php tag like               <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient ORDER BY pnum DESC"; $result = mysql_query($sql); while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $pn = $row['pnum ']; break; } ?>     and then only change the first statement of javascript write  var c = '<?php echo $pn; ?>';

Comment: <?php
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient ORDER BY pnum DESC";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $pn = $row['pnum ']; }
?>
<script>
function autonum(){ 

                         
     var c = '<?php echo $pn; ?>';

    var d = c.split("-");
    var e = d[2];
    var f = parseInt(e,10);
    var g = f+1;        
    var str = '' + g;
    var pad = "0000";    
    var resu = (pad+str).slice(-pad.length);
    var lt = d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+resu;               
    document.getElementById("pnum").value =lt;
}
</scrip>

Comment: ok..i will put that in the <head></head>?

Comment: and also comment whether success or not?

Comment: but there are error when i put that in the <head>

Comment: there's nothing appear in the textbox

Comment: <head><?php
include('connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblnpatient ORDER BY pnum DESC";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 $pn = $row['pnum ']; }
?>
<script>
function autonum(){ 

                         
     var c = '<?php echo $pn; ?>';

    var d = c.split("-");
    var e = d[2];
    var f = parseInt(e,10);
    var g = f+1;        
    var str = '' + g;
    var pad = "0000";    
    var resu = (pad+str).slice(-pad.length);
    var lt = d[0]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+resu;               
    document.getElementById("pnum").value =lt;
}
</script>

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pisystem\NewPatient.php on line 24

Comment: write php code before htlm and head tag

Comment: this is the line 24    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\pisystem\NewPatient.php on line 9..this is the error again

Comment: no. sorry.i have different variable in other pages

Comment: yes it is correct...should the $sql $result is the same to the other page/

Comment: <?php
       include('connect.php');
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblnpatient");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         echo '<tr class="record">';
         echo '<td>'.$row['pnum'].'</td>'; ?> ..this is example when i open my database

Comment: i don't have a team viewer, but the field names and the table name is correct because i checked it to my database

Comment: pnum,pname,addr,bdate,cont,age,fname,mname,sname,civil,sex,bp,bt,weight,complaints and date

Comment: ok.please wait. what will i send to you? the whole page and the database?

Comment: but the problem might be in the opening of my database in the parameter?

Comment: you send email on my id or not?

Comment: not yet..please wait sir

Comment: i will send to you all?

Comment: fast I have only 1 hour

Comment: i sent to you already

Comment: but the current value of the middle is fixed

Comment: ok i will do and send after some time

Comment: I have already sent you check it in your mail

Comment: how about BLCH-2015-0001, new counting if the year is new.

Comment: I sent you mail on your email id. Check it. In that I have already done coding if year is changed.

Comment: yeah it works..but the counting of the number is continuing..like BLCH-2014-0010, then the next year is BLCH-2015-0011. that should be BLCH-2015-0001..new year, new counting

Comment: your problem is solved.

Comment: not yet...the value of the pnum is still continuing..the BLHC-2015-0001 is appearing on the top of the banner

Comment: I had mail that to your mail id

Comment: but the incrementing of the numbers did not work